# How to make a label float with the element in d3.js?

Tags: d3.js, label

I'm working on a d3.js cluster diagram for a short time.
It's able to add new elements to clusters and move those elements across clusters.

I have added labels to elements but I didn't realize, how to make those labels move with the elements, if it is a new element.

My source is here: http://bl.ocks.org/heal25/9888263

If you add a new element, it's label doesn't works. 
Can someone help me out?

Comment: I would add `g` elements for the nodes to contain both circles and text. Then you have to move just the `g` elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you! 
I found a bug, that causes not to move a text with the element. In line 183. it must be

`label = svg.selectAll("text.node")`

and not

`var label = svg.selectAll("text.node")`